# Past tenses: did/had questions

Tags: past-tense

Which one is correct?

- TilesView **had consumed** complete screen until I *overriden* onMeasure().
- TilesView *consumed* complete screen until I **had overriden** onMeasure().

Comment: Also "*the* complete screen".

Comment: Btw, I think "entire" and "whole" sound better than "complete". It might just be me and it might be that I don't know enough about the context.

Answer (score 1):

I would word it like this:

> TilesView consumed the entire screen until I overrode onMeasure().

Answer (score 1):

"...consumed **the** entire screen until I overrode..."
or
"...had consumed **the** entire screen until I had overridden..."

The tenses need to match.  You need a definite article in there.

Comment: I thought that I need to move the first sentence more in past because it happened earlier than the second sentence